# react native- vector-icons: change the name to simple text

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I use react-native-vector-icons / Ionicons
and i want to know
If there a way to change Ionicon's name into simple text?
For example, instead of name = "md-checkmark-circle-outline"
So I want it to be just "abc" text

```
 <Ionicon
                style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
                name="md-checkmark-circle-outline"
                size={30}
                color={selectedZoneIds.length > 0 || selectedGroupId != null ? "white" : 'grey'} />
```

Comment: Why do you want to achieve it?

Comment: i just need to do the same logic but only with text ..just all

Comment: You can achieve it using a custom component that take the name and replace it with the real one from the library if you want something like this I can write an answer for you..

Comment: please show me with my logic.

Comment: I'll write an example

Comment: i just need "abc" text instead the icon ..

Comment: I've wrote an answer is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using a custom component and use the component to make the icons like this:

First you have to create an object with the name that you wants and the value for each key the real name from the library:

let create a new file called ionicIcons.js

```
  export const ionicIcons = {
   abc: 'md-checkmark-circle-outline'
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {Ionicon} from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import {ionicIcons} from './ionicIcons';

const CustomText = ({children, ...props}) => {

  return (
        <Ionicon name={ionicIcons[children]} size={30} {...props} />
    );

}

export default CustomText;
```

and you can use it like this:

```
 <CustomText  style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}  color={selectedZoneIds.length > 0 || selectedGroupId != null ? "white" : 'grey'}>abc</CustomText>
```

Comment: i cant just replace it with text ?

Comment: can you write me an example for what do you want exactly do you want it  like `<abc />`

Comment: ```
 <Text
               style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',
               color:{selectedZoneIds.length > 0 || selectedGroupId != null ? "white" : 'grey'}}}
              ></Text>
```

Comment: how i make it work?

Comment: You can't make it through `Text` component you have to add a custom component to do it, I changed my answer so you can achieve it and to add a text beside the icon add them both in the same `View`